# Signing identity and Provisioning profiles drop downs are showing as empty

Tags: xamarin.forms, app-store, visual-studio-2022

I want to archive and publish the iOS application through windows machine. Remote connection to mac and apple account login into the visual studio, everything was successful. But after archiving, the signing identity and provisioning profile drop downs are showing empty. I tried changing automatic provisioning to manual also. But, none of the tries worked. I do not know why it is showing like this. can anyone please help me on this issue. Thank you.

visual studio version: Community edition 2022 17.5.1
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can this project successfully build with auto or manual provisioning?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Yes. I selected configuration to release and tried to build. Build and archive was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know signing and publishing always bring headaches with too many details. Also too many issues reported for this.

First of all, here is the official documentation : [Xamarin.iOS app distribution overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/). Such a lengthy doc but if we want to distribute we have to be familiar with it.

Then, you could check in from the following aspects:

1. Have you created and downloaded a valid iOS distribution certificate? If you did, can it be seen in Visual Studio Apple account detail info?
2. Select a real device (not iphone simulator) when archive. Is this real device registered?

I think there is one stupid method which may work: Create the ipa (refer to [Creating an IPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows#creating-an-ipa)) and then upload it through Transporter on Mac.